Can I read a CSV straight from GitHub on Snowflake?
I see that Snowflake now supports executing scripts out of GitHub (in Public Preview), but no example shows actually reading data from a .csv.
Is this possible?

Docs examples: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/git/git-examples

Related question on /r/snowflake: https://www.reddit.com/r/snowflake/comments/1bvms9j/connect_git_to_snowflake_now_in_public_preview/ky8erlm/



It's easy to read CSVs out of GitHub. For example, out of a public repository that needs no authentication - we first need to set up the connection in Snowflake:
create or replace api integration git_plotly_datasets_integration
api_provider = git_https_api
api_allowed_prefixes = ('https://github.com/plotly')
--  allowed_authentication_secrets = (git_secret)
enabled = true;

create or replace git repository plotly_datasets
api_integration = git_plotly_datasets_integration
-- git_credentials = myco_git_secret
origin = 'https://github.com/plotly/datasets.git';

(I skipped good security practices and did it all with accountadmin)
With the git repository setup done, we can select from any file in that repo:
select $1, $2, $3, $16
from @plotly_datasets/branches/master/1962_2006_walmart_store_openings.csv;


That's great - but especially with CSVs I'd love to do some schema auto-detection. But this didn't work:

create or replace file format my_csv_format
type = csv
parse_header = true
field_optionally_enclosed_by = '"';

select *
from table(
infer_schema(
  location=>'@plotly_datasets/branches/master/1962_2006_walmart_store_openings.csv'
  , file_format=>'my_csv_format'
  )
);
-- Remote file '[...]/git_repository/e7f0f8a8-bd17-4834-adeb-5ab5bcd86192/null' was not found. There are several potential causes. The file might not exist. The required credentials may be missing or invalid. If you are running a copy command, please make sure files are not deleted when they are being loaded or files are not being loaded into two different tables concurrently with auto purge option.
--  File 'git_repository/e7f0f8a8-bd17-4834-adeb-5ab5bcd86192/null'
--  Row 0 starts at line 0, column 

(I'll file that internally as a bug)
To get the csv from github into a Snowflake table with schema auto-detection you will need to copy the csv into a traditional stage:
create stage files_stage;

copy files
into @files_stage
from @plotly_datasets/branches/master/1962_2006_walmart_store_openings.csv;

create or replace table mytable
using template (
    select array_agg(object_construct(*))
    from table(
        infer_schema(
          location=>'@files_stage/1962_2006_walmart_store_openings.csv',
          file_format=>'my_csv_format'
        )
    )
);

copy into mytable
from @files_stage/1962_2006_walmart_store_openings.csv
file_format = my_csv_format
match_by_column_name = case_insensitive;


select *
from mytable;



Great @Felipe Hoffa thats great, but you right one would expect a git stage to work like any other stage, allowing COPY or PIPE into table from  , or your infer_schema()

Is there a way to refer local repo files, so that I do not have to specify branch, I mean use execute immediate from to execute my_script.sql where I have  ```copy files
into @files_stage
from @plotly_datasets/./local_foler/1962_2006_walmart_store_openings.csv;

